# Print error message with missing parameter

Tags: rust

I have following code that works fine if parameter (the file .csv) is present. It must be, in W10 cmd:
target\debug\testecsv < file.csv
But it I enter:
target\debug\testecsv
without the required parameter "file.csv"
routine prints "begining..." and prompt keeps as "waiting" for the parameter and I must finish with Ctrl + c.
If the parameter "< file.csv" is not present, I want to print an error msg and exit the routine.
Thanks in advance.

```
extern crate csv;
use std::io;
use std::process;
use std::error::Error;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Registro {
    dia: String,
    kg: f32
}
fn lercsv() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut leitor = csv::Reader::from_reader(io::stdin());
    for l in leitor.deserialize() {
        let registro: Registro = l?;
        println!("dia {} peso foi {} kg", registro.dia, registro.kg);
    }
    Ok(())
}
fn main() {
    println!("begining...");
    if let Err(e) = lercsv() {
        println!("{}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no missing parameter. The `< file.csv` is a redirection and is handled entirely by the shell. If you omit it, your program expects to read from the TTY (i.e. you type things in). While you _could_ detect that stdin was a TTY, rather than a file (or other redirected thing), that would be an unusual way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I considered this. But how could I add code into my routine to detect that required parameter is missing?

Comment: To determine if `stdin` is a TTY, you can use the [atty](https://crates.io/crates/atty) crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted simply reads the standard input provided by the shell.
Your program is unaware of the fact that the data is read from a file.
If you want finer control over error handling, you need to parse the command-line yourself, and explicitly read the file.

```
extern crate csv;
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::process;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Registro {
    dia: String,
    kg: f32
}

fn lercsv() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // read 1st argument (after the program name itself)
    let filename = env::args().nth(1).ok_or("Missing parameter")?;
    // open the specified file and obtain a reader
    let reader = File::open(filename)?;
    let mut leitor = csv::Reader::from_reader(reader);
    for l in leitor.deserialize() {
        let registro: Registro = l?;
        println!("dia {} peso foi {} kg", registro.dia, registro.kg);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    println!("begining...");
    if let Err(e) = lercsv() {
        println!("{}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9bef46cc51c00e636404baef469abf3)